# Transparent population of fields into Pydantic sub-classes

Tags: python, pydantic

I am using Pydantic as a gateway to an API - I toss the APICall class a url and a connection identifier, which can also be extended to specify what class to use for the response, as well - ACertainAPIRequest(APICall), AnotherAPIRequest(APICall), etc.  These have a property called _response that dictates what pydantic class the response data is loaded into.

The base class has an execute function to make it easy to use with asyncio.gather(), because I often have to make multiple concurrent calls to different endpoints.

```py
class SpecificResponse(BaseModel):
    abc: str
    def: str
    jkl: str
    ...

class APICall(BaseModel):
    url: str
    id: str
    error: Exception = None
    call_type: BaseModel = None
    _response: BaseModel | dict = None
    request_time: datetime = Field(default_factory=get_utc_now)
    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True)

    async def execute(self, session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
        # Perform the actual session.get(self.url)
        # If `_response` is configured, load the results into the configured class

class ASpecificAPIRequest(APICall):
    _response = SpecificResponse = Field(default=SpecificResponse)

req = ASpecificAPIRequest(id='testing', url=path_to_api)
```

What (I think?) I would like is for the response data's class members to be the top-level accessors, and information about the request to be in a property called _metadata. So even if I use req = ASpecificAPIRequest(id='testing', url=whatever) (and later execute() it) , that id and URL should actually be in req._metadata for dev/debugging. req for all intents and purposes would be the structured response from the remote API call, just allowing for access to _metadata.

I think I could just return self._response in my execute() function, but that doesn't actually fulfill the first part of ensuring the current members of APICall are accessed through  _metadata property.

Or am I going about this all wrong?